# Launch a program whenever another one is launced

Tags: powershell, winapi, events, windows-7, windows-10

I'm trying to find a way to launch a program whenever another one is launced.
For example I want to lauch notepad.exe each time I launch MS Word.

There is a way to do that without an always running daemon?

**Edit:** As @RbMm explains [Image File Execution Options](https://blog.malwarebytes.com/101/2015/12/an-introduction-to-image-file-execution-options/) could be a way, but a recursive call of my program have to be avoided.

Maybe use `[Kernel32]::CreateProcess` with DEBUG_PROCESS flag is a solution, I'm trying to figure it out how to use `CreateProcess` and avoid the process launch loop as RbMs said.

I changed the tag from c++ to Powershell (.ps1 files could be [wrapped](http://www.f2ko.de/it/op2e.php) in an exe).

Comment: Do you have control over either or both programs (i.e. they're _your_ programs you've written?)

Comment: and who (*without an always running daemon*) will be listen on Windows Event Tracing?

Comment: however you can use `Image File Execution Options` subkey and set `Debugger` value - https://blog.malwarebytes.com/101/2015/12/an-introduction-to-image-file-execution-options/

Comment: @Tas I have control over the program auto-launced, not the one is "listened" for launch

Comment: @RbMm Image File Execution Options could be a solution, if you post an answer I'll accept it

Comment: but this not too easy solution. if under `Image File Execution Options\x.exe` you set value `Debugger REG_SZ y.exe` - when somebody exec `x.exe` **without debugger** - system exec instead `y.exe` with  "<path\>x.exe" in command line. if `y.exe` simply rerun `x.exe` - again `y.exe` will be recursively run. `y.exe`  must exec `argv[1]` but with debugging - call `CreateProcess` with `DEBUG_[ONLY_THIS_]PROCESS` flag

Comment: indeed I faced that recursive problem! Could you explain better what's your idea to solve that? I changed the tag to PowerShell.

Answer (score 2):

A few ideas:

- [DLL Injection.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa909244.aspx) If I recall correctly, you can tell Windows to load arbitrary DLLs into any/every process when they start. From there, your DLLMain function could examine the current process's name and launch the corresponding 'sister' program you want to run.
- [Task Scheduling with an Event Trigger.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa446882(v=vs.85).aspx) There may be a [security event](https://www.ultimatewindowssecurity.com/securitylog/encyclopedia/event.aspx?eventID=4688) you can trigger a task on when new processes start. This technically fails the 'no daemon' requirement, but the task scheduler should always be running anyway.
- [WMI Events.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-powershell-1.0/ff730927(v=technet.10)) This strictly fails the 'no daemon' requirement, but could be used within, say, a background powershell process to detect when new processes start.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution: Set up a batch file (or shell script) for each pair/set of programs you want to run together, and have it launch both. Then run the batch file instead of the program.

Comment: Probably because it doesn't answer the question. The question asks for a way to launch a program, **whenever** another program is launched. This implies, that there shall be no restrictions, how that other program is launched. Creating a batch file introduces an undue restriction.

Comment: True. But it satisfies the requirement "I want to launch notepad.exe each time *I launch* MS Word.

Comment: Which is prefixed with *"For example, ..."*. Could be interpreted either way, sure, but when a question is *this* unclear, it's usually best to leave a comment, asking for clarification.

Comment: That sounds like the conscientious sort of thing someone with 20k rep would do! :-) I fully admit this was a lazy late-night answer.